# PostGIS st_difference similar to ArcGIS Erase?

Tags: postgis, erase

I am attempting to replicate the ArcGIS erase tool in PostGIS.

Here is the problem I am working with

Two Layers

1. land use land cover (150,000) multipolygon table
2. multipolygon soils table (30,000)

   - both have spatial indexes

here is my query

```
CREATE TABLE agriculture.important_ag_soils_undeveloped AS
--cte selecting farmland data
with farm_to_clip AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM base_layers.ssurgo_soils_highlands_updated_stateplane 
  WHERE farmlndcl IN ('Farmland of statewide importance','Farmland of unique importance','All areas are prime farmland')
),
--cte selecting land use land cover data to erase from farm_to_clip data above
lulc_to_erase AS (
  SELECT shape FROM base_layers.lulc_huc_hl_clip 
  WHERE lu12 IN (1110,1120,1130,1140,1150,1200,1300,1500,1600,7300,1211,1400,1410,1411,1419,1420,1440,1810,1462,1463,1499,1710,1800,1804))
--now I am running this sort of messy query where I perform a st_difference for each farm polygon record and run a subquery as the second input unioning the landuse land cover where it intersects the farm polygon 
-- which yeilds the difference, and I wrap the st_difference function in the coalesce function so if it is st_difference(f.shape,NULL) then f.shape is returned for that row. 
SELECT 
  f.*,
  coalesce(
    st_difference(f.shape,
      (SELECT st_union(l.shape) 
       FROM lulc_to_erase AS l 
       WHERE st_intersects(f.shape,l.shape)
      )
    ),
    f.shape) AS geom
FROM farm_to_clip f;
```

this query takes about 5 minutes to run and I know there must a more efficient way of writing this query.

from @tilt suggestion I removed a the subselect and coalesce function and just used a left join with the st_difference function here is my updated query:

```
create table agriculture.important_ag_soils_undeveloped2 as

WITH farm_to_clip AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM base_layers.ssurgo_soils_highlands_updated_stateplane
    WHERE farmlndcl IN ('Farmland of statewide importance','Farmland of unique importance','All areas are prime farmland')
    ),

lulc_to_erase AS (
    SELECT shape from base_layers.lulc_huc_hl_clip 
    WHERE lu12 in (1110,1120,1130,1140,1150,1200,1300,1500,1600,7300,1211,1400,1410,1411,1419,1420,1440,1810,1462,1463,1499,1710,1800,1804))

SELECT f.*,
    ST_Difference(f.shape,l.shape) geom 
FROM farm_to_clip f 
LEFT JOIN lulc_to_erase l ON ST_Intersects(f.shape,l.shape);
```

Problem: the new method of using the left join returns a significant more amount of polygons in the new layer than the first query I used.

My question becomes which query gives me the farm layer erased by the lulc like the way ArcGIS performs its erase?

**UPDATE**

I used the arcgis erase tool on the farm_to_clip and lulc_to_erase and the layer that was created is the same layer that I created in my first query. My second query did not seem to work correctly at all, but I cannot figure out why..?

I am going to try unioning my lulc_to_erase geometry before I send it through the select st_difference function

```
farm = light transparent green
lulc = hatched orange
```

[image]

QUERY 1 RESULTS

[image]

QUERY 2 RESULTS

[image]

Comment: Why did you make this subselect inside your ST_Difference? It seems like this could be done with a normal LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY.

Comment: oh yeah let me try that...and I would still need the coelesce function in case the st_difference's second input (land cover) is null

Comment: @tilt I ran a left join but I returned a lot more polygon area than my first query.. now I am unsure which one is more accurate

Comment: You should get a feeling of what happened when you visually inspect the output in QGIS or ArcGis. Maybe you can share some pictures of the situation before and after?

Comment: @tilt updated, the first query seems to work but I cannot wrap my head around why the second query with the left join somehow returns more than the first query. I get that it returns all the farm rows with the left join, but if it a farm poly does not intersect a lulc poly then it will send a null geom into the st_difference function...?

Comment: and if I add wrap the st_difference inside a coalesce function it will return even more polygon area..

Comment: You forgot the ST_Union and GROUP BY in the second query....

Comment: adding that now, I'll update soon

Comment: @tilt same results with st_union and the group by's for query #2...

Comment: I'm attempting the same thing at the moment. Is your first query still the one that works or have there been any more developments?

Comment: yes only the 1st one worked, my guess is the query @tilt suggested does not work because in the st_difference function if there is one null geometry, I believe the function will not work. maybe wrap COALESCE around the st_difference function...

Comment: @Cliff check out this felllas answer,https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187406/how-to-use-st-difference-and-st-intersection-in-case-of-multipolygons-postgis?rq=1